# Spring Data JPA in two repositories for databases

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, repository

I want to use spring data jpa repository. And I have to connect to 2 databases. I already found so many similar questions. But most of answers are using Entity manager instead of repository.
For example

```
@persistenceContext(unitname = "example")
Entitymanager em;
```

But I want to use repository of spring data jpa. How can I configure in applicationContext.xml?
My 2 databases are MySQL and one is local another is remote server.

Answer (score 2):

You can separate those repositories in different packages. Then its possible to create two DB's configurations with different enity manager factory and transaction manager.

For example first config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.firstpackage",
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactoryDb1",
    transactionManagerRef = "transactionManagerDb1")
public class DB1Config {
   @Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryDb1() {
    ...
}

public JpaTransactionManager transactionManagerDb1() {
    ...
}
public DataSource dataSourceDb11() {
    ...
}
```

Second config would be similar.

You didnt put many details in question, but in case you need to switch databases for same repositories ( for example for different locales ) you can use AbstractRoutingDataSource class which will define determineCurrentLookupKey method.